# nodejs input stream using express

Tags: node.js, express, inputstream

Is there a way that using express a route consumer can send an input stream to the endpoint and read it?

In short I want the endpoint user upload a file by streaming it instead of the multipart/form way. Something like:

```
app.post('/videos/upload', (request, response) => {
    const stream = request.getInputStream();
    const file = stream.read();
    stream.on('done', (file) => {
        //do something with the file
    });
});
```

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Library https://github.com/mscdex/busboy will do that, you get each file as stream also.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Express, the `request` object is an enhanced version of [`http.IncomingMessage`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage), which *"...implements the Readable Stream interface"*.

In other words, `request` is already a stream:

```
app.post('/videos/upload', (request, response) => {
  request.on('data', data => {
    ...do something...
  }).on('close', () => {
    ...do something else...
  });
});
```

If your intention is to first read the entire file into memory (probably not), you can also use [`bodyParser.raw()`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserrawoptions):

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
...
app.post('/videos/upload', bodyParser.raw({ type : '*/*' }), (request, response) => {
  let data = req.body; // a `Buffer` containing the entire uploaded data
  ...do something...
});
```